# TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value` when I try to replace numeric values in multiple columns by a specific string value.

```
df =

TYPE  VD_1   VD_2    VD_3
AAA   1234   22122   2345
AAA   1234   2345    22122
```

This is how I do it:

```
df[df.isin([22122])] = "English"
```

or

```
df[df==22122] = "English"
```

Comment: Sorry are you trying to do this for a specific column or anywhere it appears in the df? basically the warning is saying that this is not allowed, if you did `df.loc[df['VD_3'] == 22122,'VD_3] = 'English'` then this would work

Comment: @EdChum: The thing is that I need to make this replacement anywhere in the `df` (for columns starting with `VD_`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you `stack` the df, then you can compare the entire df against the scalar value, replace and then `unstack`:

```
In [122]:
stack = df.stack()
stack[ stack == 22122] = 'English'
stack.unstack()

Out[122]:
  TYPE  VD_1     VD_2     VD_3
0  AAA  1234  English     2345
1  AAA  1234     2345  English
```

or `replace`:

```
In [125]:
df.replace(22122,'English', inplace=True)
df

Out[125]:
  TYPE  VD_1     VD_2     VD_3
0  AAA  1234  English     2345
1  AAA  1234     2345  English
```

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is an old question, but I believe this answer will be useful for some, as it will allow for replacing values based on complex conditionals.

```
In [17]: df = df.where(df!=22122, other="English")

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
  TYPE  VD_1     VD_2     VD_3
0  AAA  1234  English     2345
1  AAA  1234     2345  English
```

Note that values where the condition in the where clause is **not** met are replaced by values in `other`.